# Dell XPS improperly resuming from deep sleep

Tags: suspend, dell, 20.04, xps

I have a 2020 Dell XPS that I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on (kernel `5.4.0-29-generic`). I noticed that there was quite a lot of power drain when the laptop was suspended. I did some digging and realized that `s2idle` was the `mem_sleep` mode

```
brian:~$ cat /sys/power/mem_sleep 
[s2idle] deep
```

To have less power consumption on sleep, I switched the `mem_sleep` mode to `deep` by creating a file: `/etc/sysfs.d/mem_sleep.conf` with the contents

```
power/mem_sleep = deep
```

I rebooted the laptop and checked the `mem_sleep` mode

```
brian:~$ cat /sys/power/mem_sleep 
s2idle [deep]
```

However, when I closed the lid and re-opened it, I saw the Dell logo like it was booting up. The screen never changed - it just stayed on the Dell logo.
This model of the Dell XPS has a feature where if the laptop is shutdown, it will boot when you open the lid. I thought that might somehow be interfering, so I turned that off in the bios. No dice.

I also noticed that when I connected the laptop to an external monitor, everything on the monitor was normal. I could login and use the computer, but the laptop screen still showed the Dell logo. I have to restart the laptop to get it to display anything other than the Dell logo, which defeats the purpose of suspending the laptop.

If I switch `mem_sleep` back to `s2idle`, it works fine.

Does anyone know what's up with this?

Answer (score 2):

I came across [this thread](https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-13-9300-Wake-from-sleep/td-p/7523159). I was able to fix the issue by disabling the "sign of life" options under the "POST behavior" section in the bios.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this absolutely solved the issue for me! Note however that the only strange thing is that I cannot seem to be able to wake up (from deep sleep) using the keyboard, but only the power button. It's a minor issue, and I'm not sure if it's by design or not, but I'd still like to be able to wake up from deep sleep using my keyboard, as I do with my desktop computer.